# optaplanner machine reassignment example - drools vs java

Tags: drools, optaplanner

About the machine reassignment example:

Why in this case Java code has better performance over Drools? what is the reason for choosing Java code over Drools?

What changes should I do, in order to get better performance with using Drools?

Link to doc example: https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#machineReassignment

Link to Optaplanner examples source code: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples

Comment: What machine reassignment example are you talking about? Could you include a link to the example in your post?

Comment: I updated my question. thanks